# How to export a table in CSV format?

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, psql

I have a logs table in the data base database. For the second day I'm struggling to upload it in CSV format.

Commands like

> copy logs to 'D:/CSV.csv' WITH CSV DELIMITER ',' HEADER;

don't help. The error logs relation does not exist always pops up, while an empty CSV file is created along the path specified in the command.

Comment: [screen1][1]
[screen2][2]
[screen3][3]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjdO4.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaQMT.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9a1rp.png

Comment: Please [edit] your question, don't add details in the comments.

Comment: Please use plain text in this topic, not an image on a different website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving the problem:

Before using the command

> Copy logs To 'D:/CSV.csv' With CSV DELIMITER ',' HEADER;

Needed:

1. Log in to psql with the command `psql -U username` (according to the postgres standard)
2. The next step is to connect to the database where your table is located. In my case, this is `\connect "data base"`
3. And then you can copy the table in csv format with the command above.

I hope that this answer will help all newcomers in the same trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Either you are connected to a different database, or the schema (`public`?) is not on your `search_path`.  In the latter case, use

```
COPY public.logs TO 'D:/CSV.csv' (FORMAT 'csv', DELIMITER ',', HEADER);
```

Comment: It doesn't help. ERROR: the relation "public.logs" does not exist

Comment: Then it does not exist, and you are connected to the wrong database. Remember that a PostgreSQL database cluster contains more than one database.

Comment: and how i can connect to right database? I have only 1 (standart) user "postgres", in database "data base" there is table "logs".

Comment: There are at least two more databases: `postgres` and `template1`  Use the correct connect string.